# Align nodes in tikz chained diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I started my work from this [example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pera-model/)

After cleaning the code to understand better the commands I have this situation

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.75,
    start chain=1 going below, 
    start chain=2 going right,
    node distance=3mm,
    blocksgeneric/.style={
        scale=0.75,
        on chain=2,
        rectangle,
        rounded corners,
        draw=black, 
        very thick,
        text centered,
        text width=8cm,
        minimum height=12mm,
        fill=black!10
        },
    blocksblue/.style={
        fill=blue!30
    },
    labels/.style={
        scale=0.75,
        on chain=1,
        minimum height=12mm,
        text width=2cm,
        text centered
    },
    every node/.style={font=\sffamily}
]

% Left column
\node [labels] (L5) {L5};
\node [labels] (L4) {L4};
\node [labels] (L3) {L3};
\node [labels] (L2) {L2\\L2\\L2\\L2\\L2\\L2};
\node [labels] (L1) {L1};
\node [labels] (L0) {L0};

% Right column
\chainin (L5); % Start right of L5

\node [blocksgeneric] (B5) {B5};
\node [blocksgeneric, blocksblue, continue chain=going below] (B4) {B4};
\node [blocksgeneric] (B3) {B3};
\node [blocksgeneric] (B2) {B2};
\node [blocksgeneric] (B1) {B1};
\node [blocksgeneric] (B0) {B0};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is this. [image]

What I want is to keep the L2 labels next to the B2 block and the others in the same way.

Edit 1:
what would I do if I wanted to customize the height of one of the blocks on the right in order represent a bigger concept? The label on the left should be at the center of the block.
At the same time if a block is smaller(because I want it is small) than the label that contains a lot of text how could I keep the block small but at the same time put it at the center of the text on its left?

Edit 2:
last question: if I'd like to expand the dimension of the block B2 to the dimension of the label L2(depending on what is actually high) how can I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a chain, you can position nodes using a `\matrix`, which behaves similar to a `tabular` environment with dynamic columns. If you want to know more, have a look at the PGFmanual.

[image: There I fixed it]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.75,
    blocksgeneric/.style={
        scale=0.75,
        rectangle,
        rounded corners,
        draw=black, 
        very thick,
        text centered,
        text width=8cm,
        minimum height=12mm,
        fill=black!10
        },
    blocksblue/.style={
        fill=blue!30
    },
    labels/.style={
        scale=0.75,
        minimum height=12mm,
        text width=2cm,
        text centered
    },
    every node/.style={font=\sffamily}
]

% Left column

\matrix[row sep=3mm]{
    \node [labels] (L5) {L5}; &
    \node [blocksgeneric] (B5) {B5}; \\

    \node [labels] (L4) {L4}; &
    \node [blocksgeneric, blocksblue] (B4) {B4\\B4\\B4\\B4\\B4}; \\

    \node [labels] (L3) {L3}; &
    \node [blocksgeneric] (B3) {B3}; \\

    \node [labels] (L2) {L2\\L2\\L2\\L2\\L2\\L2}; &
    \node [blocksgeneric] (B2) {B2}; \\

    \node [labels] (L1) {L1}; &
    \node [blocksgeneric] (B1) {B1}; \\

    \node [labels] (L0) {L0}; &
    \node [blocksgeneric] (B0) {B0}; \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I add one more question about what I want to achieve. Maybe you could update this reply with the answer for the other too.

Comment: Your second goal is much easier to achieve using a `matrix`, I guess.

Comment: @usernumberone Like this?